# No se muestran anuncios Intersitials Swift

Tags: swift, admob

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Swift y tras implementar los anuncios Intersitials de Admob no consigo que este se muestre. Este es mi código, ¿qué puede ocurrir?

```
class single_noticia: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!


override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "mipub")

    let request = GADRequest()
    self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)

    let progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    progressHUD.labelText = "Preguntando en Secretaría"
    progressHUD.mode = .Indeterminate

    //Alamofire JSON GET

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        })

}
```

En la consola estoy recibiendo el siguiente error

> Google Cannot present interstitial. It is not ready.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente tienes que inicializar el anuncio con un `adUnitID` valido

```
self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
let request = GADRequest()
```

El que estas definiendo, "mipub" no es valido:

```
GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "mipub")
```

Debes tambien definir el id del dispositivo de prueba, si es que estas en etapa de desarrollo:

```
request.testDevices = ["XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]
self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)
```

Puedes realizar la validación para saber si tu anuncio esta listo para ser desplegado:

```
 if self.interstitial.isReady {
    self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
  }
```

Puedes consultar para mayor detalle la documentación **[Anuncios 
intersticial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial#adding_interstitial_ads_to_your_project)** (inglés)

Answer (score 0):

Los anuncios de tipo `Interstitial` tienen bastante contenido y tardan en cargar x tiempo. Es por ello que nada más abrir la aplicación, probablemente no estén preparados para mostrarse. Por ello, no es recomendable mostrarlo nada más abrir el `UIViewController` sino mostrarlo después de alguna acción o evento para darle tiempo a cargar.

Por otro lado, tienes una función para verificar que está preparado para mostrarse tal que así:

```
if self.interstitial.isReady {
    self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
}
```

De manera que cuando quieras mostrar el anuncio, si está preparado lo muestras, y si no lo está (por ejemplo no hay conexión) no lo muestras.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1**

En caso de no funcionar, se puede implementar el delegado `GADInterstitialDelegate` y utilizar el método siguiente para mostrar el anuncio cuando éste se haya descargado:

```
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {

    ad.presentFromRootViewController(self)

}
```

Por último, verificar los `devices` de test seteando la propiedad siguiente:

```
request.testDevices = ["xxxxxxxxxx"] // Donde las x son el identificador
```

Comment: A pesar de hacer eso y darle tiempo, nada se muestra... ¿El problema es que ejecuto desde el simulador o está en el código?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta